# dynamic menustrip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I m trying to create dynamic menu using C# WinForm Project. My database structure is mentioned below. I can create the top menu ie "FILE", "EDIT", "SEARCH". But I cannot run the recursive function for the Child menu.

```
mysql> select * from dynamicmenu;
+------+-----------------+--------+-------+-----------+
| SLN  | Child           | Parent | Level | Reference |
+------+-----------------+--------+-------+-----------+
|    1 | FILE            | NULL   |     0 | NULL      |
|    2 | EDIT            | NULL   |     0 | NULL      |
|    3 | SEARCH          | NULL   |     0 | NULL      |
|    4 | Session Manager | FILE   |     1 | 1         |
|    5 | Connect To      | FILE   |     1 | 1         |
|    6 | DO              | FILE   |     2 | 5         |
|    7 | Copy            | EDIT   |     1 | 2         |
|    8 | Paste           | EDIT   |     1 | 2         |
|    9 | Find Text       | SEARCH |     1 | 3         |
|   10 | Cut             | EDIT   |     2 | 7         |
|   11 | VMS             | FILE   |     3 | 6         |
+------+-----------------+--------+-------+-----------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The c# code is as follows.

```
mysqlConn conn;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn = new mysqlConn();
    conn.OpenConnection();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from dynamicmenu", conn.connection);
    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (dr["Parent"].ToString() == "")
        {
            menuStrip1.Items.Add(dr["Child"].ToString());
        }

        else if (dr["Parent"].ToString() != "")
        {

            AddSubMenu(new ToolStripMenuItem(dr["Child"].ToString()), dr["Parent"].ToString());
        }
    }
    dr.Close();
    conn.CloseConnection();

}

private void AddSubMenu(ToolStripMenuItem ChildItem, string ParentItem)
{
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menuStrip1.Items)
    {
        if (ParentItem == item.Name)
        {
            item.DropDownItems.Add(ChildItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: What is the exact problem? What do you mean "I cannot run the recursive function"?

Comment: The "AddSubMenu" Part is not working. Only "if (dr["Parent"].ToString() == "")" is working.

Comment: Your AddSubMenu() method completely ignores the fact that a menu is a *tree*.  You treat it like an array so you can only ever find the top-level menu items.  Recursion is the natural fit for tree traversal.  You are also completely ignoring the fact that a menu isn't just text, storing the Click event handlers in the database is the other 95% of the job you still have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `toString()` instead of `name`.

```
private void AddSubMenu(ToolStripMenuItem ChildItem, string ParentItem)
{
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menuStrip1.Items)
    {
        if (ParentItem == item.ToString())
        {
            item.DropDownItems.Add(ChildItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you just copied the OP's method.  You might want to change *something* to make it work.

Comment: At least make it clear what you changed and how it answers the question. A bare code dump does not make a good answer.